# install PySide2 on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyside2

Trying for days but can't install PySide2 on python 2.7.15 while got no problem on python 3.7.
On Qt for python(which is the project name for the module PySide2) website at is written explicitly that python 2.7 is supported so that should be no problem.

I succeeded installing PySide2 on python 3 using:

```
pip install PySide2
```

then i tried installing PySide2 on python 2 using:

```
python -m  pip install PySide2
```

which yelled error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2(from versions: none)
```

which means there is no such module for 2.7 even though at is written in Qt for python website that python 2.7 is suported.

also tried installing using Pycharm directly and failed with the the same error.

there is no even a single tutorial showing fully how to install PySide2 on python 2.7.

Comment: PySide2 supports python2 but the package uploaded to pypi is only for python3, if you want to use PySide2 in python2 you must compile it.  See the section of Building "PySide2 from scratch"
 in https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted . IMHO python2 in a short time will be maintained so you should migrate to python3

Comment: I tried but it very complicated and I did not succeed to get it right...
there is no easier way?

Comment: No, use python3 :-), it's the easiest solution for you

Comment: Eventually i just converted all my 1000 lines code to python3... did not found any other solution for python2

Comment: Maybe [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) helps you a little in it.

Comment: Tried it before, did not work right for me. thank you for your help @eyllanesc

Comment: Please don't just answer "use Python 3"  A lot of people are forced to use Python 2.7 since it's the only version supported in most VFX software such as Maya and Houdini

Comment: From looking at the available official PySide2 wheels there's no precompiled wheel for 2.7 on Windows, right now looks like you have to compiled it your self.

Comment: @Geordie, the DCC applications already include PySide2 so you need to install it just for standalone applications that could (and probably should) be built for Python 3.

Comment: That's my point.  just because something could or should be true doesn't mean it's the reality of some peoples development reality.  Sometime for whatever reason you're stuck with a crappy old codebase and answering "just use python 3" instead of trying to solve the problem isn't helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The pip install approach pulls the wheels from the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/#files). If you look at the available wheels for cp27 (Python 2.7), there are only wheels for Linux and MacOS platform. I'm assuming you are using a Windows Platform, which returns the error message as you have shown.

If there is no support on the pypi platform, your only way is to build PySide2 from the source on your platform. This [document](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted-windows.html) shows how to build from source. However, according to this very document, it does not support Python 2.7 interpreter.

> Note: Python 2.7 interpreter is not supported. The official Python 2.7 binary package offerred on the official website is built using MSVC 2007, while the Qt libraries are built using MSVC 2015/2017. **If you intend to use Python 2.7, build the interpreter yourself with MSVC 2015 or later, and build Qt for Python with it.**

The bolded statement is your answer.